# How to force OpenAPI Generator CLI to use pre-downloaded .jar file?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, openapi-generator, ubuntu-22.04, openapi-generator-cli

I have installed (via npm) openapi-generator-cli on my WSL running Ubuntu 22.04 image, with correctly configured HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables.

The problem is, running any command (including `sudo openapi-generator-cli help`) results in OAG-CLI attempting to download the .jar file from maven.org, which end with connection getting refused for unknown reason (SSL cert not listed as trusted? WSL-exclusive bug? corporate proxy having an edge case?).

Instead of dealing with all that, I realised I can just download the latest ([as per official website](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation/)) .jar file:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/6.2.1/openapi-generator-cli-6.2.1.jar
via browser and **place it manually** for OAG-CLI to use.

I have edited the auto-generated `openapitools.json` just so:

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "6.2.1",//same version as .jar
    "storageDir": "."//see below
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, despite placing two copies of the .jar file (one named `openapi-generator-cli-6.2.1.jar`, one named `openapi-generator-cli.jar`) in both the "current" folder and `/usr/libs/openapi`, and trying the following values for `storageDir`:

- `.`
- `./`
- `/usr/libs/openapi`
- `/usr/libs/openapi/`
- `~/usr/libs/openapi`
- `~/usr/libs/openapi/`

every single run of `sudo openapi-generator-cli help` resulted in an immediate `Downloading 6.2.1 ...` message (followed by `connection refused` error some time later).

**What else do I need to do to make OAG-CLI use the .jar within `storageDir` instead of trying to download a new copy?**

(Answer containing just the structure and contents of a folder created by `"storageDir": "~/foo"` would allow me to reverse-engineer a working setup.)

Comment: Apologies for any typos within the example CLI commands - I don't have access to my work computer with the notes containing the actual CLI commands used.